# how does an if condition and a return false statement execute the condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

im trying to solve the leetcode valid parentheses problem and im running into one part of code i dont understand.

```
var isValid = function(s) {

    let newBrackets = []

    for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        switch (s[i]) {

            case '(':{
            newBrackets.push(')');
            break;
            }

            case '{':{
            newBrackets.push('}');
            break;
            }

            case '[':{
            newBrackets.push(']');
            break;
            }

            default: {
                if(s[i] !== newBrackets.pop()){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newBrackets.length === 0;
};
```

i dont understand how the defaut: if statement pops the newBracket last element. i thought it was just a condition but supposedly it pops the last element. apologies if i didnt word my question properly

i asked chatgpt and it just said newBrackets.pop() method is called though im not understanding how if it is an if condition

Comment: First it calls `newBrackets.pop()`. That removes from the array and returns the element that was removed. Then it compares that with `s[i]` to evaluate the `if` condition.

Comment: Do you think function calls work differently inside `if` conditions? It's just an expression like any other.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a JavaScript programmer.

Comment: @Pointy exactly which is why i asked here lol

Comment: @Barmar so essentially it runs the newBrackets.pop() first, removing the last element then it checks the condition?

Comment: Of course. All operators execute their arguments first (except short-circuiting operators like `&&` and `||`).

Comment: Think about it: the `!==` test cannot be evaluated unless `newBrackets.pop()` has returned a value.

Comment: Would you be confused by `if (prompt("Enter a number") == "3")`? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: @Barmar ahh makes sense yes thats true i guess they have to be executed in order for the if statement to run. not sure why I was confused by that but thanks for clearing it up

Comment: Beginners often think these things are more complicated than they are.